# Replace multiple when by jinja code

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Instead of a multiple launch with the key "when:":

```
- name
...
when: {{ environnement }} in 'pp'

- name
...
when: {{ environnement }} in 'pd'
```

I would like to do it this way directly in a yaml :

```
{% if {{ environnement }} in ('pp','pd') and if {{ module }} == 'publish' %}
- name: ...
{% endif %}
```

Is it even possible without template?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [blocks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_blocks.html). Example from docs:

```
 tasks:
     - name: Install Apache
       block:
         - yum: name={{ item }} state=installed
           with_items:
             - httpd
             - memcached
         - template: src=templates/src.j2 dest=/etc/foo.conf
         - service: name=bar state=started enabled=True
       when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'
```

For your scenario:

```
- block:
    - name: ...
      ...

    - name: ...
      ...
  when: environnement in ['pp','pd']
```

P.S. and don't use `{{...}}` within `when` statements, they are already Jinja2 expressions by itself.

Comment: Yes block may interest me! Also I want to try :
`code`
    - name
      {% if {{ environnement }} = xx %}
      command...
      {% if {{ environnement }} = yy %}
      other command...
    when: environnement in ['xx','yy']

Comment: This is bad way to do things in ansible... Will make playbook unreadable

Comment: oh! the idea for me was to be clearer than copying twice the same commands for changing 2 values depending on the environnement variable... But maybe it's just simplier to read without jinja :)